# Regex: Excluding phrases where main search word is in the middle

Tags: regex

I'm trying to exclude terms that might occur with my main search expression. To illustrate: I would like to get text that matches `bar` but doesn't have `foo`, `abc`, `cde` before or `foo`, `bcd`, `def` after so I have the following through negative lookahead/back:

```
(?<!(foo|abc|cde)\s)bar(?!\s(foo|bcd|def))
```

This works well but I need to exclude a phrase where bar is in the middle but I need to accept other occurrences where the start (ex `one`) and end (ex `two`) word/s are not used together. My scenarios/requirements are:

- Accept: one bar abc
- Accept: qwe bar two
- Don't accept: one bar two

If I add `one` or `two` on the negative lookahead/back such as

```
((?<!(foo|abc|cde|one)\s)bar(?!\s(foo|bcd|def|two)))
```

it won't accept `one bar abc` and `qwe bar two` too. Is there a way to do this in one expression?

Demo here: https://regexr.com/63q0s

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. Sorry if it sounded unclear. I have edited my post to make it clearer that when I do add `one` and `two` it will exclude other phrases that I need.

Comment: Right, you need `(?<!(?:foo|abc|cde)\s)bar(?!(?<=one\sbar)\stwo)(?!\s(?:foo|bcd|def))`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBvpaQ/1). Or, `one bar two(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!(?:foo|abc|cde)\s)bar(?!\s(?:foo|bcd|def))`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBvpaQ/2).

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew! Learned something new today. I'd mark it as an accepted answer if my post reopens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PCRE compliant regex that you can use is based on `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs:

```php
one bar two(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!(?:foo|abc|cde)\s)bar(?!\s(?:foo|bcd|def))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBvpaQ/2). Here, `one bar two(*SKIP)(*F)|` is an alternative that is tried first, and once the `one bar two` is matched, the match is discarded and the next match is searched for from the failure position.

Another approach is using nested lookarounds:

```js
(?<!(?:foo|abc|cde)\s)bar(?!(?<=one\sbar)\stwo)(?!\s(?:foo|bcd|def))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBvpaQ/1). The added `(?!(?<=one\sbar)\stwo)` lookahead matches a location that is not immediately followed with a whitespace and `two` string that are immediately preceded with `one`, whitespace and `bar` string.